# How to capture selected element from dropdown in razorview and send it using POST?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Below is my razor view. I am populating my dropdown from my controller's passed list.
I need to send item that was selected from the dropdown list to send it to my api.

```
 <div id="body">  

            @model List<Data>

            <select>
                @foreach(var item in Model)
                {
                    <option value="@item.value" >@item.value</option>
                }
            </select>


            <form id="sendstuff">

               @*TODO need to send what was selected in the dropdown here*@

                <input class="btn" type="submit" id="createAccount" value="Send Stuff" />

                <br/>

                <div id="apiresponse"></div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#sendstuff").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var options = {
                url: "api/CreateSomeAccount",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#sendstuff').serialize()
            };

            $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
                $("#apiresponse").html(data);
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Jscript here sends json post request to web api and grabs apiresponse back from the api and replaces the view's #apiresponse. What I want to do is to
send the option that has been selected in the dropdown and send that option to this json ajax post request.

Here is the controller code. It is a json file and passing the list of "Data" from the file to the view.

```
namespace Something.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JsonFileLocation"])))
            {
                string jsonData = r.ReadToEnd();
                List<Data> testsNamesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(jsonData);
                return View(Data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to send it? And how? You don't have it in the form... do you have a button for this?

Comment: I have updated the question. Hopefully this clears things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with one solution using javascript. Basically when the dropdown is selected, it populates the textbox with the dropdown selection and when I submit, the populated field in the textbox will be sent to api.

```
$('#dropdown').change(function () {
    $('#textbox').val($(this).find(":selected").text());
});
```

This is not the ideal solution, but if anyone else has better solution please feel free to answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <select name="dropdownValue">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option value="@item.value">@item.value</option>
    }
    </select>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

and get the value by add string parameter called dropdownValue to your action method

Comment: I do want to include my options in the form. See my above updated question. This might help you better answer my question now.